# Unable to build R project

Tags: r, lazy-loading, rstudio, cran

I'm building an R project in RStudio (Version 1.0.136), on Windows 10, using the *igraph* and *statnet* libraries, and calling a number of C functions using `.C()` within R functions.

The build is failing with this output:

```
* installing to library 'C:/Users/Joanna/Documents/R/win-library/3.3'  
* installing *source* package 'cycleanalysis' ...  
** libs  
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.  
installing to C:/Users/Joanna/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/cycleanalysis/libs/x64  
** R  
** preparing package for lazy loading   
unable to reach CRAN  
Error in .C("cycleCensusID_R", as.integer(dat), as.integer(n), as.integer(NROW(dat)),  : 
  "cycleCensusID_R" not available for .C() for package "cycleanalysis"
Error : unable to load R code in package 'cycleanalysis'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'cycleanalysis'
* removing 'C:/Users/Joanna/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/cycleanalysis'

Exited with status 1.
```

My code setup is that the R function `kcycle.censusExtended()` calls the C function `cycleCensusID_R()` as follows:

```
#Calculate the cycle information
ccen<-.C("cycleCensusID_R",as.integer(dat), as.integer(n), as.integer(NROW(dat)), count=as.double(count), cccount=as.double(cccount), as.integer(maxlen), as.integer(directed), as.integer(tabulate.by.vertex), as.integer(cocycles), PACKAGE="cycleanalysis")
```

When running this in the console in Rstudio, as shown below, this is the error I receive:

```
cc <- kcycle.censusExtension(adjacencyMat, maxlen = 5, tabulate.by.vertex = FALSE, cycle.comembership = "bylength")
Error in .C("cycleCensusID_R", as.integer(dat), as.integer(n), as.integer(NROW(dat)),  : 
  "cycleCensusID_R" not available for .C() for package "cycleanalysis"
```

Any idea why I might be getting these errors or how I might solve them?

Comment: I think the hint is in this line: “make: Nothing to be done for `all'.” — your C library isn’t being built for some reason.

Comment: i) Don't use `.C()`. These days *everybody* recommends `.Call()`. ii) If I had to guess you fail to load the dynamic library via `NAMESPACE`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I've tried replacing .C() with .Call() with no improvement.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, I do suspect a problem with the C library not being built but I can't see a how to fix this. The line "make: Nothing to be done for 'all'." is stating that each source in 'all' has already been built, since this is not a clean build. A clean build has the same final outcome.

Comment: @Joanna That is not a copy-and-paste.  Read Writing R Extension. Use working packages as examples.  Start small.  As small as possible.  Get that to work.